# macOS could not be installed on your computer

Tags: macos, mac, high-sierra, install, mac-mini

I have a Late 2011 Mac mini late 2011. It had macOS High Sierra installed, but due to some problems with language, I decided to delete everything and re-install it. But Now, I have this message when the Mac Mini restarts after the first installation:

[image]

I even chose the deep analyze by Apple Diagnostics from internet and other where the RAM has been checked and No issues were found, it doesn't detect any kind of problem.

I have a late 2011 Mac Mini, 16GB RAM, and an SSD Harddrive.

What should I do?

Comment: A few things that could cause this is faulty ssd/hard drive or faulty RAM, try the installation again and enable the installer logs so you can see how far the installation goes before halting.

Comment: Did you follow the prompts on the screen to run Apple Diagnostics?

Comment: @fsb yes, I did. I even chose the deep analyze. No issues were found.

Comment: @Maximus the RAM has been checked by Apple Diagnostics, there were no issues found.

Comment: Ok, you should [edit] the question to add it so you're not asked the same thing over and over.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to find a solution!

The USB key that I used was crashing during the installation. Therefore, I went with Internet Recovery mode, and it is successfully installed.